# Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "web/static/js"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to build a vagrant server for dabbling with elixir and phoenix, but after installing all requirements and dependencies, and on running `mix phoenix.server` I'm getting the following error:

> error: Compiling of 'web/static/js/app.js' failed. Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "web/static/js" ;

I'm not sure of the context of 'preset' here, I'm hoping a more seasoned phoenix user will know what it's getting at.

Some cursory Google's gave me nothing, other than it might be something to do with babel.

Edit: I just tried installing what I assume to be the missing package, `sudo npm install babel-preset-es2015 -g`, but it hasn't resolved the error.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Please see the fix here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1410

1. Upgrade to node >= v5.0.0
2. npm cache clean
3. cd my_app
4. rm -rf node_modules/
5. npm install
6. mix phoenix.server

Comment: Thanks, Chris. It only worked for me after also bumping npm to >= v3.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I also needed to update npm.
npm -v # if it's less than 3.0
npm install npm -g

Comment: You've made my day

Comment: @Chris McCrod is this answer still relevant? I'm seeing new answers that indicate this no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

I see that there is already an accepted answer here. I just encountered the exact same error, and tried the solution Chris posted above. It did not work for me, but based on the github issue link Chris posted above, I found a solution that worked for me.

I found that you don't necessarily need to be using node v5.0+. I am using node 4.4.3 LTS, and things are working.

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: As you'll see in my OP that was something I tried with no success. It could be that our issues were different, or of course that something changed in the time that passed.

Answer (score 2):

My solution which is great works:

```
.pipe(babel({
    presets: [require('babel-preset-es2015')]
}))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

I had to remove the `.babelrc` in the parents directories of my app.