# Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/username"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I get the following error when trying to use gulp-babel:

> Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory
>   "/Users/username"

I have the es2015 preset installed globally and locally so can't see why this would be an issue.

Below is my gulp set up and package.json.

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var es2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');

gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/main.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: [es2015]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.1.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

I am using node v5.1.0 and babel v6.4.0

Here is the terminal ouput

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMwPp.png)

Comment: I think you need to pass a string in the `presets` array, like `['es2015']`, I am not very sure though

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks but same issue as a string.

Comment: You didn't require gulp. Maybe that could be the cause `var gulp = require('gulp');`

Comment: @AndreiCacio I have included gulp it just isnt in the code snippet. I have only included the code relevant to the babel compiler.

Comment: Do you happen to have a `.babelrc` file in your home directory? Since that is where it is looking for the preset, that means that is where the configuration is coming from.

Answer (score 122):

You only need to install `babel-preset-es2015`:

CLI usage example:

```
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: this solved it for me ... WoW what a terrible error message :  Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/path/to/node/package/attemping/to/install" ... especially painful when trying to install some random npm package which uses gulp and babel

Comment: npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!

Answer (score 14):

To fix this issue You should remove .babelrc (hidden) file from "/Users/username" directory.

Answer (score 12):

the "es2015" in :

```
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
    }))
```

is actually a path - so if you don't have the preset in the /Users/username/es2015 directory you have to point exactly to it like for instance:

```
.pipe(babel({
    presets: ['../../gulp/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015']
}))
```

it worked for me

Comment: also worked for me using an absolute path to the "babel-preset-es2015" folder

Comment: This may seem overly simplistic, so I'm only adding it as a comment, but make sure you spell everything right.  I had the label as 'es2105' with the digits transposed and it had me scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 8):

I just used this exact gulpfile.js

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var es2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/main.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: [es2015]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

and it worked for me. I only installed `babel`, `babel-preset-es2015` and `gulp-babel`.

Comment: Could you tell me your version of babel and node. 

I have the same set up as you can see. but still that same error

Comment: I am using node 4.0 and babel 6

Comment: Updated description with terminal output

Comment: It might be a windows related issue or smth like that. I have found a similar thread that you can check out: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/354 maybe it will shine a light on the problem.

Comment: Try to uninstall the `node_modules` folder and reinstall fresh all packages

Comment: another related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345573/couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory-web-static-js

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have seen both of those. Will keep digging for a solution.

Comment: Loading `babel-preset-es2015` explicitly as shown here solved my issue.

Comment: Make sure .babelrc is configured correctly for babel 6.  The format for 6 is `"presets": ["react", "es2015"],`

Answer (score 8):

You could try installing `es2015` and `stage-2` via

```
npm i babel-preset-es2015 --save
npm i babel-preset-stage-2 --save
```

Answer (score 7):

Check if you have .babelrc file in the root folder of your Project. If not create .babelrc file and add the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and it was because I had a `.babelrc` file in the root of my directory.

To fix this add `babelrc: false` inside the babel options:

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/main.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        babelrc: false,
        presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: +1 i found an `.babelrc` file in my root and this was the problem. the config `babelrc: false` seems not work, but when i delete everything works!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and this second suggestion helped me noticing my problem and maybe it's yours too.

I `npm install gulp-babel-es2015` then didn't include it in the gulpfile at all.

Then `babel({presets: ['es2015']})` option is just a string as shown in the examples here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel .

**Here is my gulpfile.**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('babelify', () => {
    gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('alljs'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['babelify']);
```

Also, as from this issue here, https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/354

Suggestions are you should update node to version 5.x.x and npm to 3.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

The situation where I encounter this problem is that I have moved the files from `xxx` to `xxx/server`. And then under `xxx/server` I will see the `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/username/xxx"` error.
The real reason is that I have forgotten to move that `.babelrc` file under `xxx`. And after I move that `.babelrc` to `xxx/server`, the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a really weird one. I installed all the babel tools with one big long `npm install` command, and everything installed without errors... except it was throwing the error documented in this thread, at runtime.

I noticed the version was 0.0.0 in the package.json file, so I ran `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` again and it worked and placed a SECOND key into my package.json file:

```
   "devDependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
     "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-preset-es2015": "0.0.0",
     "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
     "eslint": "^3.19.0"
   }
```

I just removed the botched entry and it cleared up this `relative to directory` error.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that other program was using a file involved in the compilation process (probably the .babelrc). Closing several apps solved my problem.

For me was Dropbox or even Brackets Editor with eqFTP extension.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

### Babel 7 update

From the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#yearly-preset-deprecations-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-deprecated-yearly-presets-eg-babel-preset-es20xx) you should now use `@babel/preset-env` instead of any other `preset` mention

> The "env" preset has been out for more than a year now, and completely replaces some of the presets we've had/suggested earlier.
>
> - babel-preset-es2015
> - babel-preset-es2016
> - babel-preset-es2017
> - babel-preset-latest
> - A combination of the above ^

```
yarn add @babel/preset-env
```

or

```
npm install @babel/preset-env
```