# Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I get the following error when I trying to use babel.

> Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    ourput: {
        path:'./',
        filename:'index.js'
    },
    devServer:{
        inline:true,
        port:3333
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                loader:'babel',
                query:{
                    presets:['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "es6-react-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Terminal output
[image: Terminal output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/username"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819473/error-couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory-users-username)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have babel configured to use those presets. You can add this to your `package.json`

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
```

You can alternatively have a `.babelrc` file.

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Answer (score 8):

Try this

> npm install babel-preset-es2015
>
> npm install babel-preset-react
>
> npm install babel --save-dev

This worked for me.