# Ember serve doesn't work (Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015")

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli

I am building a web app using Ember. I created the project with `ember new test-app` and have made no changes to the generated files. When I run `ember serve`, I immediately receive the following error:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees: Addon#compileAddon(ember-welcome-page) ] failed with:
Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/jacob"
    at /Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map ()
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at Promise (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/lib/parallel-api.js:102:26)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at new BroccoliMergeTrees (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:16:10)
    at Function.BroccoliMergeTrees [as _upstreamMergeTrees] (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:10:53)
    at mergeTrees (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/merge-trees.js:85:33)
    at Class.compileAddon (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:1092:12)
    at Class.treeForAddon (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:746:26)
    at Class.treeForAddon (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-welcome-page/index.js:27:41)
    at Class.superWrapper [as treeForAddon] (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at Class._treeFor (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:557:33)
    at Class.treeFor (/Users/jacob/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:517:21)
```

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474327/error-couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory) for help, but I still received the same error after trying the solution.

I am running ember-cli v2.16.2 and node v8.9.0 on macOS High Sierra. In my node installation, the only three global modules I have installed are bower, broccoli-cli, and ember-cli.

Answer (score 2):

Please do clean reinstall of ember-cli package.

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g ember-cli
```

Then run your ember new command once again and test it.