# Yarn installation, Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"

Tags: npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I need to use `react-select`: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select
For that I needed to first install `yarn` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. After the installation, and `yarn add react-select` I can not build my project anymore with `webpack` since it is giving me the error:

> ERROR in ./views/index.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome"
>       at /home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
>       at Array.map ()
>       at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
>       at OptionManager.mergePresets (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
>       at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
>       at OptionManager.init (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
>       at File.initOptions (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
>       at new File (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
>       at Pipeline.transform (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
>       at transpile (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
>       at /home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:118:18
>       at ReadFileContext.callback (/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/client_side_BrainImmuneConnectome/brain-immune-connectome/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:31:21)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:437:13)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! brainimmuneconnectome@0.0.0 webpack: `webpack`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the brainimmuneconnectome@0.0.0 webpack script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/nikita/.npm/_logs/2018-06-07T04_11_30_458Z-debug.log

I have presents installed in `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]
}
```

So, the solutions that I found here:

[Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474327/error-couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory)

are not working. What is going wrong here? How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/93

Doing the following:

```
npm i babel-preset-es2015
npm i babel-preset-stage-2
```

Solved the issue.