# GitLab-CI Cache - Phoenix Framework - Couldn't find preset “es2015”

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gitlab-ci

I'm experiencing the same problem outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345573/couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory-web-static-js). However, this is happening to me when I use `gitlab-ci` to build my container - but only when I use the cache feature.

Given the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix
ARG MIX_ENV=prod
ENV MIX_ENV ${MIX_ENV}
ARG PORT=4000
ENV PORT ${PORT}
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mix deps.get --only prod
RUN npm install
RUN mix compile
RUN brunch build --production
RUN mix phoenix.digest
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD mix phoenix.server
```

The following error occurs when the `brunch build --production` line fires:

> Compiling of web/static/js/socket.js failed. Couldn't find preset
>   "/app/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015" relative to directory
>   "web/static/js" ; Compiling of web/static/js/app.js failed. Couldn't
>   find preset "/app/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015" relative to
>   directory "web/static/js" The command '/bin/sh -c brunch build
>   --production' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here's what my build job looks like in `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - review
  - staging
  - production
  - cleanup

build-image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest

  # When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
  # improved performance.
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

  services:
  - docker:dind

  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

  script:
    - docker build --pull --build-arg MIX_ENV=prod -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

  only:
    - branches

  except:
    - master
```

I've confirmed that the `/app/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015` folder exists and I've tried following the directions from the link (above). Deleting the `node_modules` folder or cleaning the npm cache does not appear to help.

The one thing that does work is disabling the gitlab cache. I was able to avoid the issue by building a new branch (therefore, creating a new cache). However, the problem came back. Building without a cache always works.

Am I missing something with by `gitlab-ci` cache configuration? Also, is there a way to reset the gitlab cache (I'm using the latest production on [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com))

Comment: You did install npm, but brunch should be installed as well.

Comment: phoenix uses a non-global approach to use brunch, where they list it as a dev dependency in package.json and call it by running `node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch` 

That doesn't seem to be the cause of the error here though